texlive 2024 / chemnum: error when referencing unknown IDs
Using texlive 2024 chemnum generates an error when referencing an unknown ID.
Using texlive 2018 the expected "??" is written in the pdf.
MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemnum}
\begin{document}
    \refcmpd{a}
\end{document}

log:
Runaway argument?
{}\prg_break_point:Nn \prop_map_break: {}\chemnum_write_main:nnnn {\c_false_boo
l \ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \__prop_map_tokens:nw.

Any ideas how to fix this? Thanks

chemnum hasn't changed since 2021, so I would guess this is a change in expl3, we'll look....

Not obvious from the error what is up: I’ll take a look later

chemnum tries to get an item from a not existing prop. This is not correct but didn't error previously. Due to a change in the prop code it now fails. Your example works again if you add a test:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemnum}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set:Npn \chemnum_expandable_get_compound_property:nn #1#2
  { \prop_if_exist:cTF
      {g__chemnum_compound_#1_prop}
      {\prop_item:cn {g__chemnum_compound_#1_prop} {#2}}
      {\prop_new:c{g__chemnum_compound_#1_prop}}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\refcmpd{a}
\end{document}

You should report this to the chemnum maintainer.

My feeling is we should document that ..._item generally work only with defined variables.
